# Raspbian Lite does not load rndis_host driver for Tethering

Tags: raspbian

I have a Pi4 running latest and completely fresh Raspbian, I'm trying to connect a 4G LTE modem through USB to setup a link so I can use the Raspberry Pi as NAT to enable multiple devices to use the 4G modem.

The modem works on other Raspberry distros like Ubuntu, and also x86 laptops running distros like Mint. This is what `usb-devices` says:

```
T:  Bus=02 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#= 10 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=2001 ProdID=7e40 Rev=03.18
S:  Manufacturer=Mobile Connect
S:  Product=Mobile Connect
S:  SerialNumber=0123456789ABCDEF
C:  #Ifs= 3 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=03 Driver=rndis_host
I:  If#=0x1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=0a(data ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=rndis_host
I:  If#=0x2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
```

But in Raspbian, the rndis_host does not get loaded at all:

```
T:  Bus=02 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#= 10 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=2001 ProdID=7e40 Rev=03.18
S:  Manufacturer=Mobile Connect
S:  Product=Mobile Connect
S:  SerialNumber=0123456789ABCDEF
C:  #Ifs= 3 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#=0x2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
```

It just loads the mass storage device (the router has a SD Card slot it serves as a mass-storage device, as can be seen).

This is what the kernel (`dmesg`) has to say:

```
usb 121.4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hed
usb 11.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2020, idProduct=2030, bedDevice= 3.18 ush 1-11.41 New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 1 1.3: Product: Mobile Connect
usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Mobile Commect
usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
usb storage 1-1.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
scsi host: usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0
scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SD Storage  0318 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
scsi 0:0:0:1: CD-ROM        Mass Storage    0318 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 
sd 0:0:0:0: [sdal Unit Not Ready
sd 0:0:0:0: [sdal Sense : 0x5 [current]
sd 0:0:0:0: [sdal ASC=0x20 ASCQ=0x0
sd 0:0:0:0: [sdal Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x00 dr iverbyte=0x08 sd 0:0:0:0: [sdal Sense Key : 0x5 [current]
sd 0:0:0:0: [sdal ASC=0x20 ASCH=0x0O
sd 0:0:0:0: (sda) © 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B,0 B)
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0-byte physical blocks
sd 0:0:0:0: [sdal Write Protect is off
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: Of 00 00 00
sd 0:0:0:0: [sdal Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn’t support DPD or FUA sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
scsi 0:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sgl type 5
sd 0:0:0:0: [sdal Unit Not
sd 0:0:0:0: [sdal Sense Key : 0x5 [current]
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda) ASC=0x20 ASCH=0x0O
sd 0:0:0:0: [sdal Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08 sd 0:0:0:0: [sdal Sense Key : 0x5 [current]
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda) ASC=0x20 ASCH=0x0
sd 0:0:0:0: [sdal Attached SCSI removable disk
sr 0:0:0:1: [sr0) scsi-1 drive
cdrom: Uniform CD ROM driver Revision: 3.20
iform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
0:0:0:1: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
```

So no information, it's as if it's not seeing anything at all, just the mass storage device.

I tried loading the driver manually with `modprobe rndis_host`. It put out no output, which means that it was successful(?). Whatever the case, the behaviour is the same, so this didn't help.

But why is this? How can one USB connection even function as three seperate ones (When its detected properly, it loads three seperate drivers as can be seen from the first output, so three logical devices if I understand right).

How can I get past this problem?